# C++ How to wait until a condition is met?

Tags: c++

In C++ how can I wait until a condition is met for example - Pseudo code:

```
bool con = false;
waituntil(con);
//do whatever
```

Comment: Depends on your use case. Do you want busy waiting? Waiting for an interrupt? Waiting for another thread to finish something? Sleeping with periodic checking?

Comment: When will the condition be met?  There is a big difference in the solution, depending on if you are wrinting kernel level code, emebedded code, multithreaded code or just expecting signals to change the bool.

Comment: Once i type something into my Qt line edit

Comment: @Hamish So if you are using threads, what kind of threads?  Standard C++ `<thread>`?  You need to provide more code in order to give context...show the condition changing, the files you include, etc.

Comment: Im asking you what to do I'm just running a basic program I'm not coding no OS

Comment: @Hamish Okay, now you've edited your comment to say you are using Qt.  That makes a big difference, and if you don't mention it then people can't be psychic.  It still doesn't *necessarily* mean you're using Qt threads (you could be using Qt for the UI only, and standard threads).  But I'll try and be "psychic" and suggest you look at [QWaitCondition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html).  This has nothing to do with how complex or simple what you are writing is...you really need to put more details into your questions when you ask them, we can't guess.

Comment: @Hamish Also, if you want to respond to events on editing of a Qt edit (on keypress, or otherwise) then you don't generally need threads to do that, you do that with key event filters.  Multithreaded programming is by its nature complex--you don't have to be writing an OS for it to be tricky.

Comment: I assure you: I/we **want** to help, but there just isn't enough information here to work with, and I'd only be _guessing_ at what you'd need. Is it possible to make a [mcve] in Qt, the tiniest application that has a `QLineEdit` and the behaviour you wish to see, assuming [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37106086/4143855) doesn't help.

Comment: Please indicate what you are trying to do by providing some context to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qt API you could use a [QEventLoop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) like this:

```
QEventLoop loop;
QWidget::connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```

Your application while continue to be responsif but will not exit that loop until the edit is finished on the [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) object.

You are free to use any SIGNAL that is relevant to you or even create a custom one as soon as the user click on the [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)

Comment: This is certainly a way, but my gut feelings keep telling me that asker just doesn't know much about signals and slots, and he doesn't really need to "wait until condition is met", but rather needs to "execute when event is fired". I think you could help him better by also including an example of more general signal-slot connection to a custom slot function, where actual "waiting" for condition happens (without any waiting, de facto).

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. Looks like "22 words-questions" do not provide enough information to help someone without guessing most of the problem! I'll come up with a nice custom QObject if it's really what the OP wants :).

Comment: @TheRealNox -- Your response was valid with the information provided imho - i will try to write up a clear example with some good practices in it

Answer (score 0):

In response to comment from The Badger, I apologize for being too vague.
 Here's a complete explanation of how the code below all works.

You could use a Q_PROPERTY macro combined with a method like the one @TheRealNox  described.

The Original Post asked how to perform a specific action when con is equal to true
   it said:

```
    waituntil(con);
   // do whatever
```

Well, Below I have outlined one possible way that you can perform an action using Qt whenever the boolean typed object named  "con"  changes. This method uses  Q_PROPERTY to set up a signal to emit by specifying the NOTIFY  keyword.

```
  Q_PROPERTY(bool con  MEMBER con NOTIFY con_changed)
```

The important part to notice here is the NOTIFY con_changed part. 
By adding in the words NOTIFY  followed by a signal (in this case con_changed),  essentially whenever the MEMBER changes (in this case "con"),  it will send out the signal  "con_changed"  so that other parts of your program can "hear" the signal and react accordingly.

Lets take a look at this example  header file, which is explained below the example.

In myclass.h

```
class MyClass : public QObject {

    // emits the   'con_changed' signal whenever   con changes
    Q_PROPERTY(bool con MEMBER con NOTIFY con_changed)   

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
        bool con;
    signals:
        void con_changed(bool new_con_value);
    public slots:
       void check_con_value(bool new_con_value);
}
```

Now if you look at the code in this first box,  you will notice that I have specified a SIGNAL  by using the "signals:" macro which has the same  signature (name)  as the one mentioned in the Q_PROPERTY's NOTIFY parameter. (in this case it is con_changed)

A signal is essentially one way for an object to talk to another object using Qt, and is thread-safe.

Also in the code above, you should note that there is also a "public slots:" section  where I have defined  the method   "check_con_value(bool new_con_value).

This will be a slot which is connected to the signal  "con_changed", essentially making it so that whenever  the "con_changed"  signal is sent, it will automatically cause  the slot:  "check_con_value"   to execute. However, as of now the slot check_con_value  and  con_changed  are not connected together yet, which we will do in the next file.

in myclass.cpp

```
     #include "myclass.h"
     MyClass::MyClass(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
         con = false;
      // connect the con_changed signal to execute check_con_value
         connect(this, SIGNAL(con_changed(bool), 
                 this, SLOT(check_con_value(bool));
     }



    void MyClass::check_con_value(bool new_con_value)  {

        if (new_con_value == true) {

            /***********        
             *
             *   here's where you perform whatever actions you want
             *
             **/

         }

    }
```

There are two things happening in the above code that are important to take note of.

The first thing is that I have  connected the signal "con_changed"  to the slot "check_con_value"  by using the connect method. basically connect works  by typing in  connect(sender,  SIGNAL,  receiver,  SLOT).  I feel like explaining connect is outside of the scope of this response,  but anyways,

The second thing happening above is that we have  put in the code for  the "check_con_value" slot,  which will execute whenever  con_changed is sent as a signal.  Inside of that slot you will notice  there is a conditional if statement which says:

```
if (new_con_value == true) {
   // execute your code here.

  }
```

So,  essentially what this means, is that if you set up your program using Q_PROPERTY definitions, then anytime you want to wait until  con is true then execute some code when that happens, you can just set  con  to false like this:

```
 con = false;
```

and then whenever it changes to  true, the code will execute.

This might be overly complicated, but the original post was only a single sentence, so based on the information contained in it, this is as close as I could really get to answering their question.

There are other solutions, depending on the use case for this particular functionality, this may or may not be the ideal way to go about setting up a wait condition.

In fact, there are other simpler solutions, however this way is a more organized and clean way to perform the desired functionality.

I guess it all depends on what the use case is, which wasn't included in the OP.

Comment: I do not see how mentioning Q_PROPERTY is of relevance to the question or the answer. Perhaps I am missing something but what you show is normal [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), no need to complicate it and confuse readers with the Q_PROPERTY. Also, your implementation is not correct, Qt will not automatically emit the signal if con is changed, that is why Q_PROPERTY expect a write method so that you handle the emit in your code when someone calls the setter with a different value than the current.

Comment: @The Badger -- I will add additional verbal explanation

Answer (score -2):

To wait until a condition is met, you need to have your program loop the portion of the code that includes the conditional.

For example:

```
bool con = false;

while(programIsRunning) {

    //your program

    while(con) {
         //wait until con
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not do that. It will use a lot of processing power for nothing. Have a look around the semaphore paradigm. (cf [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)))
Basically, a mutex and a boolean should get you a good start for a semaphore class.

Comment: BTW, `con` is a very bad word in French ;) and `while(con)` sounds very funny. That's right, busy wait is con. Also, it's conditional, so it's like if you still believe that people can change.